# Am I running Bash?

Tags: bash, command-line

I am using OS X 10.8.5. I am trying to figure out if the terminal is running bash. When I type in the following it says "getent" command not found -- but the error message seems to be coming from bash.

```
Me$ getent passwd $(whoami) | awk -F: '{print $NF}'
-bash: getent: command not found
```

Am I running bash?

Comment: . 
. . yes . . .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your shell is `bash` and you have it trying to run `getent`.  The reason it puts `-bash:` before `getent: command not found` is because otherwise it would look like `getent` was telling you it couldn't find a command.